# Is IBus stopped developing?

Tags: kde, ibus

Is this project became abandoned? As Bcooksley stated at this [post](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=225&t=108047&start=30#p308080), the authors has stopped developing IBus, and this is the reason why Kubuntu removed the Language Option in the System Settings. I want to have a confirmation. Is it dead? Or is it just not suitable for Kubuntu

Comment: Can you describe this project a bit more? Is it this one? http://cangjians.github.io/projects/ibus-cangjie/

Comment: No, I just mean the IBus in general, not a specific language input.

Comment: Can you be more specific though? Which IBus are you referring to? That term is used in a variety of ways.

Comment: The IBus like this: https://code.google.com/p/ibus/
I mean the basic one that many language input based on. I don't know how to give more detail.

Comment: So, what is your opinion?

Comment: The forum has activity, it would seem to be active still, but I'm still researching: https://code.google.com/p/ibus/issues/detail?id=1697&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: If you mean the forum is https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ibus-user, then I don't think it's still active because not so much people in there, and many questions aren't responded.

Comment: Not the forum you've linked, the issue tracker that the project uses, the URL I provided.

Comment: So as a user, where should I post to ask? Because it says that user should go to the link I provided to ask.

Comment: The link I posted is meant for asking Q's opening issues with the project. This would seem to be an issue they should address.

Comment: Just for making sure, so that I can go to your link to ask without the knowledge of delevoping it? I'm just the user, not developer thought

Comment: Sure, that link is for anyone not just devs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments of @slm, the answer is no. You can go to https://code.google.com/p/ibus/ to ask an question.